# NSURLSession.sharedSession shows old data when run?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

Very peculiar problem I'm running into.

I'm using session.DataTaskWithURL like this:

```
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {

            return completionHandler(nil, error)

        } else {
            if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as? NSDictionary {


                if let uDataArray = jsonResult["data"] as? [NSDictionary] {



        println(uDataArray)


} 
      return completionHandler(self.dataArray, nil)
    })
    task.resume()
```

All seems great, except that the jsonResult is displaying old data. For example, if I delete entire arrays from my API endpoint, the change is not reflected in the jsonResult property at all. Ever. It's like the data is being cached.

I use all kinds of different programs to verify that the change on the backend was made, but the app won't reload new data.

If I delete the app, run this session.DataTaskWithURL again... it pulls the current server information.

Is there automatic behavior I'm not understanding, if so, how do I stop it from caching data?

Comment: I am facing same issue. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you clear the cache of app, because session store it's data in cookies and if he get again same URL then its show that cookies data, that why you get older data. So If you clear the cache then you will always get latest data which stored on server.

```
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy:
    NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData,
    timeoutInterval: 10.0)
```